# Call Jquery Function - load content via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I am looking how i can call a javascript id through a href, or something similar inside a grid table (KendoUI).

This is the html template.

```
<script id="description-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a id="toggleShowIncident" data-code="#: id #">#: generaldescritpion #</a>
</script>
```

And this is the function that i would like to call,

```
                $("#toggleShowIncident").click(function(e){
                var data = $(this).data('code');
                var splitter = splitterElement.data("kendoSplitter");

                splitter.ajaxRequest("#left-pane", "/incidents/ajax/show/" + data);
                });
```

I cannnot pass any other "#" inside the template as it brakes the KendoUI template. As Example `<a href="#" id="id">`

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried creating a "general" event listener and checking for the ID in it? something like `$(a).click(function(e){...` also you could try: `$("#toggleShowIncident").on("click", function(e){`

Comment: i tried this `$("#toggleShowIncident").on("click", function(e){` but whithout success, i supposed because i cannot do href="#" :( , tried to add `onClick="toggleShowIncident"` . Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#` inside a Kendo template, you just have to escape it like `\\#`. But that is not your problem. You have to bind the click to the grid with a filter, e.g.:

```
// Grid initialization
$("#yourgrid").kendoGrid(...);

// Event binding
$("#yourgrid").on("click", ".toggleShowIncident", function() { ...
```

That way, any element(this include elements added after event binding, in case of dataSource reload, for example) with **class** `toggleShowIncident` will be listening to that event. You must change the `id` to class in order to repeat it along the grid.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/azosOrEC)

Comment: it works perfect, however, i am facing issue as i am getting the grid throug ajax call, and when i am clicking on row to access the content with the ID it says `splitterElement is not defined` - i tried to recreate the splitterelement variable, it works but it brokes the splitter (in multiple splitters) any idea how to bypass this?

Comment: i did it like, this, maybe i am wrong ? `$("#grid").on("click", ".toggleShowIncident", function() {
        var data = $(this).data('id');
                    var splitter = splitterElement.data("kendoSplitter");
                    splitter.ajaxRequest("#centre-pane", "/incidents/ajax/show/" + data);
            });`

Comment: @tphil Idk what is that *splitterElement*, you didn't specified it in your post.